# Power button functioning as volume up key

Tags: asus-zenfone-5

I just want to know if it is a software or hardware problem?
What I think is If the key is working fine and performing different function, It must be software problem but I am afraid that I I tried anything I might not able to turn it back on again. neither I would be able to enter recovery mode

Comment: Two possibilities; First: A kernel problem, your phone thinks you push the Vol Up button. Second: A physical problem. When you push power button, it triggers the other button on phone's chip.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR It's most likely a software problem

### Check for incorrect ROMs or button remapping root mods

It sounds like a software problem. Do you have custom ROM installed? Is your phone rooted? With either of those two cases, you likely have some software setting that overrode the button mapping of the hardware keys. Perhaps you installed a ROM that was designed for a slightly different version of your phone.

In any case, the functionality of the power button cannot be rewritten at the hardware level. I feel confident in telling you that you should be able to turn off your phone, and the power button will act as a power button to turn the phone back on. That's built in to the hardware, and only after the ROM boots should it be able to act as a different button.

If you want to test it safely, I suggest pressing and holding the power button for 15 seconds, (don't use the Android power menu to turn the phone off). Almost all Android phones will force shut down if you hold the power button down for long enough, including the [Zenfone 5](https://www.google.com/search?q=asus+zenfone+5+force+power+off).

In the case that it's only a software problem, your volume will turn up (as if you are holding the volume up button), but then the lower-level hardware will still shut the phone down after you continue to hold the button down. Since the phone detected the power button and shut down, you can be confident that it will detect the power button to turn back on.

### If holding the power button down for 15 seconds doesn't power off the phone:

If, on the other hand, the phone does not turn off after holding the power button down, and it only acts like a volume button, then you may have some bizarre hardware problem.

Perhaps the phone got wet and the contacts got shorted. The Asus Zenfone 5 has the power button and volume buttons next to each other (are you sure you are actually pressing the power button and not the volume button?). In this case, if holding the power button down for 15 seconds doesn't turn the phone off, then try the rice bag method to dry out the phone. Normally, these methods tell you to turn the phone off, but if you are already out of warranty, I suggest keeping the phone plugged in and on, or else it may never turn on again if indeed the power button is completely broken.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what happened my phone got wet, But I opened the cover  and dried it out before turning it on. After It switched on it had this problem. Do you think it will solve the problem if I replaced the button flex.Or will the rice bag method work ? And also it's not rooted.

Comment: Also the power button and volume up keys(not volume down key) turns on the screen when it is locked, but once the screen is on they both work as volume up key

Comment: I did as you said, and holding the key down turned phone off. But I wasn't able to turn it back on. So instead I connected it to charger while holding volume key and it switched to fastboot mode and I issued command from my system after connecting it with usb to simply reboot it and I turned it on

Comment: I tried factory reset too, It didn't work

Comment: I tried enabling the setting to **disconnect call with power key** and I observed that It ends the call and then increase the volume too.

Comment: Could you just tell me if **changing the power button flex** would fix it or not ? I can buy it online and replace it on my own

Comment: O is there any way to check **button mappings** ?